# My sql query is not executing on server with use session?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have found record from login table but my mysql query is now executing.

following is my code.

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." 
             WHERE mobile_number='".$mobile_number."' AND 
                   password='".base64_encode($password)."'";    
// End
$select = mysql_query($sqlQuery);
$result = mysql_num_rows($select);

echo "<pre>Rest";
print_r($result);
```

It's always return `0` but same query is working in `Phpmyadmin` dashboard.

When i used `mysql_error()` function with `mysql_query`  like following

```
$select = mysql_query($sqlQuery) or die ('Error updating database: '.mysql_error());
```

It's given error : `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Following is my connection code..

```
$dbname = "######";
$host = "localhost";
$user = "#####";
$password = "#####";

$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die("Error in database connection.");
if (!$connection)
{
    return false;
} 
if(!mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection)) 
{
return false;
}
```

I don't know why i faced the problem if anyone have idea about this pleas help me on this.

Thank You!!

Comment: First: Did you check the contents of `$sqlQuery` and are sure it is *exactly* the same query that you’ve tested in phpMyAdmin? Second: Are you aware of [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)?

Comment: Yes, I have checked same query and it's working fine in phpmyadmin

Comment: check your database.php file. have you define username there?

Comment: what version of PHP is it?

Comment: Please check your DB connection details.

Comment: @SwadeshDash , connection is working fine.

Comment: @RamRaider, Php version 5.4

Comment: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) is for connection

Comment: OK - just wondered if it was php 7+

Comment: fyi: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: `Access denied for user ''` indicates you aren't passing a user for the `mysql` connection.

Comment: @user3783243, My connection is already working , look i have put my connection code also.

Comment: Your error is `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. That is 100% a connection error.

Comment: NO, My others query is working i have checked , Connection is working well

Comment: What other query? How can you say "no"? That is the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you gotta connect to your SQL Server with username and password. Error message says you didn’t even pass a username.

Simple example:

```
$link = mysql_connect('example.com:3307', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
…
// do your stuff here
```

Please be sure to – *at least* – secure your parameters be escaping them with `mysql_real_escape_string()` for instance:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Or, even better, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE mobile_number = :mobile_number');

$stmt->execute(array('mobile_number' => $mobile_number));
…
```

Comment: Did you even read your error message? `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Answer (score 0):

- You should check the host, user name, and password in the configuration file and make sure that the information is consistent with the information given by the MySQL server administrator.
- Reset the password and try it out:

  > Enter `set password for 'root'@'localhost'=password(' your password ');`Then restart the mysql service.Enter `mysql-u root-p`